# How to implement EditText overwrite mode with custom cursor in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to implement an editText which only accepts 5 numeric characters.
 But EditText should be in overwrite mode and cursor should be box brackets. When cursor is on third digit, EditText should be similar to this:

00[0]00

And when the user click 2, it should be like this

00[2]00

Is there any way to do this custom edittext?

Comment: U need to add textwatcher for edittext and you just add [ when length 2 and add] when ever length is 4.edit text limit is 7

Comment: to make it clear, the bracket cursor should be able to slide left or right. when user clicks a number, it should be overwritten to old value